# How to assign an ID or Class to specific Webpart in Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, web-part, css, cms

I’m working with Sharepoint on a client project and I’m finding it a bit cumbersome to navigate. I see that Sharepoint seems to generate dynamic ID names for its web parts when they are created; an example would be `MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4`.

I’m not having any issues accessing this particular `<div>` in a vacuum, my CSS/JS usages are functioning properly. My issue lies with the dynamic nature of the naming convention. Let’s say I hard code some JS to look for `MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4` and then hide this `<div>` when you click a button. **It works until you start to add additional web parts or remove other web parts that existed prior to the creation of the one I’m trying to work with.**

It’s already happened to me on one occasion, after deleting an unused web part that was being hidden (`display:none` by a previous dev) it caused all the web parts to shift their names accordingly. `MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4` became  `MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3` and so forth.

My ideal solution is to simply circumvent this entirely by either assigning each web part with a unique id/class that Sharepoint won’t be changing, but I can’t for the life of me figure out how to achieve this.

Perhaps there is a more graceful solution that omits my idea entirely?

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent question. The one I have struggled with for several years in the past. Here are my thoughts on this.

I assume you are branding the look and feel of the OOTB SharePoint webpart pages.  Judging by the question, you are probably trying to style the title area of the webparts. Or the borders around the webparts.

**If you are targeting `MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ*`, you are doing something wrong**

- You will have issues when SharePoint is upgraded. In different versions of SharePoint HTML markup can be significantly different. Even when you upgrade from SP 2013 to SP 2016/2019, the changes can break your lovingly crafted CSS customizations
- If the site migrates to SharePoint Online, all of these customizations will be gone.
- It's not recommended and strongly discouraged by Microsoft.

**If you need to style webparts, don't rely on the `MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ*` IDs**

If you still need to brand your SharePoint page, do not use the `MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ*` IDs. Use something else, that's not dynamic. Ideally, target HTML of the contents of the webpart.

**If you still need to use some kind of a unique ID**

- Using JavaScript, search for the webpart's unique title. Or webpart's unique ID. For example: `webpartid="fc5342d8-ada8-4f91-9d08-e452490c01ac"`
- Inject your custom ID or CSS to the webpart's HTML
- Then, in your CSS, you can use this new CSS ID or class that will never change unless someone renames the webpart.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! I will go read up on some documentation for each solution.

Comment: Looping back to this months later. As my project scaled, I realized any work around were not going to be feasible. I ended up writing a ton of javascript to generate all my html programmatically. I create one container div in sharepoint —> JS pulls data from sharepoint lists —> magically displays. I no w have full control of all content inside the ecosystem!

Comment: Good. But bear in mind that whoever will need to upgrade your SharePoint farm or migrate it to SharePoint Online will likely struggle with these customizations. These customizations might need to be removed eventually. So don't invest too much effort in it.